# React Native bottom tab navigator and stack navigator not working properly

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have the following screen layout:
If user is not logged in: Onboarding => Set goal => Available goals (and then set button here would bring one to the hoome screen)

If user is logged in (a bottom tab bar should appear):

```
.
├── Home screen (the one previously mentioned) 
│   ├── Track screen
├── Challenges screen
│   ├── Challenges detail
│       └── Set challenge
├── Store screen
│   ├── Store detail
```

And 2 more with similar structure.

I have a few stack navigators and a bottom tab navigator but they don't work properly. Either the stack navigation doesn't work, giving me the error: "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Track"} was not handled by any navigator." Or, the bottom tab appears but stack navigator doesn't work. Or, the home page appears with a back arrow that goes back to onboarding, which should not be visible after setting a goal and proceeding further.

Here are my navigators, in 2 different files:

```js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name='Onboarding'
        component={OnboardingScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: "", headerTransparent: true }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name='Setgoal'
        component={SetgoalScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: "", headerTransparent: true }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name='GoalDetails'
        component={AvailableGoalsScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: "", headerTransparent: true }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name='Tabs' component={MainContainer} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Track' component={TrackScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Tabs' component={MainContainer} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const ChallengeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Challenges' component={ChallengesScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Details' component={ChallengeDetail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const StoreStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Store' component={StoreScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name='StoreDetail' component={StoreDetail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
export {
  AuthStack,
  HomeStack,
  ChallengeStack,
  LeaderboardStack,
  StoreStack,
  ProfileStack,
};
```

And bottom navigation:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function MainContainer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={homeName}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;
            let routeName = route.name;

            if (routeName === homeName) {
              iconName = focused ? "home" : "home-outline";
            } else if (routeName === profileName) {
              iconName = focused ? "person" : "person-outline";
            } else if (routeName === challengesName) {
              iconName = focused ? "golf" : "golf-outline";
            } else if (routeName === leaderboardName) {
              iconName = focused ? "medal" : "medal-outline";
            } else if (routeName === storeName) {
              iconName = focused ? "cart" : "cart-outline";
            }

            return <IonIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "#ED904C",
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: "grey",
        })}
        style={styles.tabStyle}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={challengesName} component={ChallengesScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={leaderboardName} component={LeaderboardScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={storeName} component={StoreScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={profileName} component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And my main navigator that I call in App.js

```js
const loggedIn = true;

const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {loggedIn ? <HomeStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

With this structure I can't go from the available goals screen's set goal button to the home page as it is giving me the The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator. I have also tried giving the route like: navigation.navigate('HomeStack', {screen: 'Home'}) but it is giving me a similar error.

I need some help on how to make it work properly pleaseeee thank you.

ETA:  Updated App.js file:

```
const getIsSignedIn = () => {
  return true;
};

function App() {
  const isSignedIn = getIsSignedIn();
  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {isSignedIn ? (
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Challenges" component={ChallengesScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Leaderboard" component={LeaderboardScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Store" component={StoreScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={MainContainer} />
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingScreen}  options={{headerTitle: '', headerTransparent: true}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Setgoal" component={SetgoalScreen} options={{headerTitle: '', headerTransparent: true}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="GoalDetails" component={AvailableGoalsScreen}  options={{headerTitle: '', headerTransparent: true}}/>
      </>
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}
```

Comment: At the last step, you are supposed to change the isSignedIn state, not navigate. React will handle the rest. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#dont-manually-navigate-when-conditionally-rendering-screens

Comment: Ohhh, I get it now!! Didn't realize it, thanks!